# Xhprof / xhgui : xhgui - document to insert contains invalid key: keys cannot contain "."

Tags: php, mongodb, xhprof

I'm trying to setup Xhgui with Xhprof.
I followed the github instructions (https://github.com/perftools/xhgui),
but this error message keeps appearing in error logs :

> "xhgui - document to insert contains invalid key: keys cannot contain
>   ".": "main()==>load..."

Looks like mongoDB can't use dots in keys, but yet Xhgui is trying to do that.

Is there a way do disable this limitation in mongoDB ? Or to fix this bug in Xhgui ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/perftools/xhgui/issues/209#issuecomment-339281276

> For anyone experiencing this issue, I was able to make it work by
>   adding the following snippet of code to xhgui/external/header.php
>   right before ignore_user_abort(true); call. Not sure how correct is
>   this and if it could affect anything else, but it did the trick for
>   me.

```
    $profile = [];
    foreach($data['profile'] as $key => $value) {
        $profile[strtr($key, ['.' => '_'])] = $value;
    }
    $data['profile'] = $profile;
```

Comment: thanks! in the version I am using as of Jan 2020, this snippet now goes into the file: xhgui/vendor/perftools/xhgui-collector/external/header.php